# UnsatisfiedLinkError in linux working with eclipse

Tags: java

i am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
no HelloWorld in java.library.path
```

when i am executing the java code in linux .
i have set the java.library.path to correct place and libHelloWorld.so is getting genrated there also but still at the time of running it saying that exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
no HelloWorld in java.library.path
```

Comment: check this link http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-how-to-handle-unsatisfied-link-error/

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this before in linux and resolved the issue by passing the VM argument `-Djava.awt.headless=true`

Also try to execute `ldconfig -p` in linux to check if java libraries are in proper place.